# How to programmatically display public calendar on own calendar?

Tags: apex, calendar, public-calendar

I have a `public calendar` that is shared with a `public group`. An observation I've made is that you have to manually add a calendar that has been shared with you. It doesn't automatically appear on your calendar. Is there a way to fulfill this programmatically via `apex`?

I'm able to query all the `public calendars` and get the `id` using the following query :

`Select Id,Name From Calendar Where Type='Public'`

The part I'm stuck at is how I can add this `public calendar` on my own `calendar` **WITHOUT** needing to manually add the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, i had the same requirement and tried few methods but could not make it happen.

It is possible to use the [CalendarView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_calendarview.htm) object to create a Calendar based on an SObject and assign it to a particular Salesforce User. But you can't do the same for Public & Resource Calendars.

I have found an Idea that is talking about the same feature, so you might promote in order to get the feature in a future release, here is the [link](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003bjRQAQ)

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign the Id of the public calendar to the PublisherId of the CalendarView that is to be inserted.

```
    Group userGroup = [
      SELECT Id 
      FROM Group 
      WHERE Name = 'Marketing User' 
      LIMIT 1
       ];
    List<Id> groupId = new List<Id>();
      groupId.add(userGroup.id);
      
   List<GroupMember> groupMembers = [
                       SELECT UserOrGroupId 
                       FROM GroupMember 
                       WHERE GroupId IN: groupId
                                   ];

  List<CalendarView> calendarViews = new List<CalendarView>();
 for (GroupMember groupMember : groupMembers) { 
     CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(
             Name = 'TestingPubl', 
             SobjectType = 'Event', 
             StartField = 'StartDateTime',
             DisplayField = 'Subject', 
             OwnerId = groupMember.UserOrGroupId,
             publisherId = '023040000006uhfAAA'//This is the Id that we get from 
                                              //SELECT Id FROM Calendar
             );
     calendarViews.add(calendarView);
     }  

     insert calendarViews;
```